# Subversion: Possible to determine file check-in times without server connection?

Tags: svn, repository

I have a working copy of a SVN repository, but due to a server failure, the remote SVN server/repository is lost.

In the working copy, there is the ".svn" directory with a "wc.db" file in it, among others.

My question is: Is it possible to get information about the repository/working copy out of those files? I'm especially interested in modification times / check-in-times of the files in the working copy.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a program that will let you execute queries against a SQLite database, point it at wc.db. In my case, I have a WC named "Documentation" and I've downloaded sqlite3.exe.

```
C:\...\_Projects\Documentation\.svn>C:\_apps\sqlite3.exe .\wc.db
```

This drops me into the SQLite command shell.

```
C:\...\_Projects\Documentation\.svn>C:\_apps\sqlite3.exe .\wc.db
SQLite version 3.7.14.1 2012-10-04 19:37:12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select local_relpath, changed_date, last_mod_time from nodes;
```

From here, you'll need to format the timestamps to get something usable. See the [SQLite docs for a reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). I tinkered with it a bit but didn't get very far. You'll probably need to dive into the SVN WC library to figure out how to interpret these timestamps properly.

**NOTE**: This data is only as good as the last time you ran `svn update`.

But without a solid backup of the real repository, you're just putting band-aids on and cobbling things back together.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the `wc.db` is just an sqlite database, so grab yourself a sqlite database tool and open teh file up (if you dont want to work it out via command line).

Couldn't tell you what is inside of it however as i dont have a db file to look at, but with an sqlite browser tool, you should be able to work that out for yourself.